# Javascript return array through http request

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I am opening a PHP file with http request:

```
// Load PHP File for Ajax
function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request.responseText, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}
```

However, that (url) will be returning an array as so in PHP:

```
return array(
  'xml' => $googleMaps->generateXML($results),
  'results' => $googleMaps->getResults()
);
```

So when I call the function as so:

```
  // generate xml and markup map
  downloadUrl(searchURL, function(data) {
    var xml = parseXml(data);
  }
```

I want to be able to distinguish between the xml and results indexes in the array. I return it as data. I'm just confused on how to parse just the xml and not the entire array.

Comment: Have you tried: `var xml = parseXml(data['xml']);` ?

Comment: It says undefined when I alert data['xml']

Comment: Then when I alert data or try to html() it to a div, it says can't find any of the files I'm including in PHP when they are right where I'm saying they are. But when I do alert(data['xml']), it loads fine and just says undefined. So for some odd reason when I alert data and that's it, it goes all haywire.

Comment: Can I not return XML and a php array of results from the database in the same call? Or will I need to call two separate scripts?

Comment: When you alert the `data` variable, what do you have?

Comment: Well when I'm echoing the array in the php file I'm calling, it says it can't convert array to string so I take out the echo and just leave array(blah blahblasdkfj), and then it's just blank when I html() it into a div or alert it.

Comment: Because in order to get the XML, it sends out a header so I feel I can't return xml and php in the same page.. that I have to do two separate calls